# Stripping whitespace in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Consider the following table, `tab`:

```
id   fruits
1    orange, banana
2    orange
3    apple, banana, grape
```

I want to "explode" this table on the `fruits` column:

```
select

id
individual_fruit

from tab

lateral view explode(split(fruits, ',')) the_fruits as individual_fruit
```

Which gives me this:

```
id individual_fruit
1  orange
1   banana
2  orange
3  apple
3   banana
3   grape
```

The leading whitespace in several of those rows makes it difficult to join this new table with other tables. How can I strip the whitespace in the new `fruit` column? I'm used to Python, and some of Hive seems Python-esque, so something like `map(str.strip, individual_fruit))` would make sense to me (but this obviously doesn't work in Hive!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` 2nd argument is regex

```
select  t.id
       ,f.individual_fruit

from    tab t
        lateral view explode(split(fruits, '\\s*,\\s*')) f as individual_fruit
;
```

---

```
+-----+-------------------+
| id  | individual_fruit  |
+-----+-------------------+
| 1   | orange            |
| 1   | banana            |
| 2   | orange            |
| 3   | apple             |
| 3   | banana            |
| 3   | grape             |
+-----+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways I solved my problem.

You could use `translate`:

```
translate(individual_fruit, ' ', '')
```

But this really only works when spaces are the only whitespace in your string. This approach gets hairy when other whitespace type are included.

Or, use `trim` to remove all leading and trailing whitespace

```
trim(individual_fruit)
```

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this problem, perhaps using `regexp_replace`, but my question is answered using the approaches above.

Comment: Over complicated solution.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz care to elaborate? "Over-complicated solution" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Have you seen the answer I have posted? P.s. No reason to use `ltrim(rtrim(...))` when `trim` is supported.

Comment: Ah, I must've missed `trim` when I was looking for Hive string functions initially. Cheers.